# Get differences between a tag and a branch?

Tags: svn, version-control

What is the easiest way to use SVN log (or something else?) to get a list of all changed/added files from a tag to a branch?

I was originally using svn log to export to XML the differences between the revision number of the tag versus the revision number of the branch but this missed files that were added to the trunk while the previous tag was still a branch (if that makes sense).

A - old branch that is now a tag
B - current branch being worked on
C - trunk

We need the list of added/changed files between A and B.  The issue is our current SVN log command is missing some files that we added to C when A was still a branch being worked on.  Once we were done working on A we tagged it then merged it with the trunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
svn diff <branch_1>[@rev] <branch_2>[@rev]
```

Comment: I am looking to get a simple list of the changed files.  I tried with --summarize which works for the most part but it still includes files that were deleted.  I checked the help page but didn't see a way to only get the added/modified?

Comment: Even when trying --no-diff-deleted it still shows some files as being deleted in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I use the SVN plugin for eclipse, which has a petty good tool to compare the two.

My favorite tool to use for this type of thing is BeyondCompare by Scooter Software. I think they have a free 30 day trial version you can use. I just checkout the tag and branch to my local drive and then use BeyondCompare to see the differences.

The best part of that product is it will highlight the characters that are different on a line and show them side by side, which make it easier to see. I find it a lot easier to use than SVN to compare code myself.

Comment: Well the problem here is we are automating patches using the command line so we are parsing the output to generate some patch files so GUI tools like you mention won't work here.  Sorry didn't mention this in question.

Comment: No problem. I hope you get an answer from someone that works for you.